# Exploring and Downloading files from a device over wifi connection

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wireless, flashair

I want my android application to connect to a device like [FlashAir](http://www.toshiba-components.com/FlashAir/index.html) over **wifi** connection and **explore** its **directories** and **download** the selected files to the android device.

I have gone through [this post](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html) and got some idea how to **scan** and **detect** devices over wifi. Now how can i access its **file directories** and **download** the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a browser or webview, you could follow this tutorial to create your own app that will list all files and directories in the FlashAir and will allow you to download image files:

https://flashair-developers.com/en/documents/tutorials/android/3/

Answer (score 1):

Any brower can connect with with the card. So you can do too using a http client. Just look in a conventionel browser how the urls are set up.

Comment: i dont want to use a browser or webview. I want to list the directories and files in android device and download the selected one.

Comment: I understood that right away. So use a http component to download the list. You only need the browser first to understand how you have to compose the urls for the http component.